Provided Metadata instance has version 2.1.0, while maximum supported version is 2.0.0. To support newer versions, update the kotlinx-metadata-jvm
I tried to geneate the apk in Flutter, and then it show me this error:
ERROR: R8: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided Metadata instance has version 2.1.0, while maximum supported version is 2.0.0. To support newer versions, update the kotlinx-metadata-jvm library.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable
Compilation failed to complete

This is my android/build.gradle:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

And this is my app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.mynoona.noona"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.mynoona.noona"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

And this is my setting.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.3.2" apply false
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.15" apply false
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.1.0" apply false
}

include ":app"

And this is my gradle.properties:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4G -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true


I don't know if is this the best way, but for me solved changing version of the kotlin.android plugin to 2.0.0.
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.0"


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Instead of downgrading back to 2.0.0, you could do exactly what is suggested in the error message and add this dependency to build.gradle:
runtimeOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.9.0")

